# Is General Grievous based on Georgios Grivas?

Tags: star-wars, general-grievous

In Star Wars, General Grievous is a military strategist that leads the Separatist Droid Army of the Confederacy of Independent Systems.

In real life, there is Greek Cypriot general Georgios Grivas, a Cyprus-born general in the Greek Army, leader of the EOKA guerrilla organisation and EOKA B paramilitary organisation.

Was Grevious based on Grivas? Is there support for this?

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely. Doubt that Lucas even know about this relatively minor historical figure.

> With General Grievous, I wanted somebody who was reminiscent of what Anakin is going to become, which is a half man, half robot. In this case, Grievous is sort of 20% alien and 80% robot."      ―George Lucas on the creation of Grievous

Comment: Grievous is also based in part on Kali from Ray Harryhausen's film the Golden Voyage of Sinbad.